# Synonymize [xna] and [xna-4.0]

Tags: discussion, tags

[xna](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xna) × 2796

[xna-4.0](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xna-4.0) × 657

These tags mean the same. I think we can assume, that user is using the latest and last version of XNA (4.0). So when looking for xna tags, user expects to see 4.0 tags also.

There's third tag also [xna3.1](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xna3.1) with 6 questions. XNA 3.1 and 4.0 has differences, so maybe that should be left alone?

I just feel that users looking for certain tags, expect certain results. Looking for unity,xna, monogame,sdl..etc, should bring all versioned stuff, but looking for versioned tag, should return only questions tagged with that.

I am not saying that we should delete all versioned tags or anything, but these two most used xna tags are synonyms.

EDIT: 
There is currently 318 questions that have tagged xna and xna-4.0.

Comment: I believe questions with 'versioned' tags should also be tagged with the main 'base' tag, i.e. a question with the [tag:xna-4.0] tag should also have [tag:xna] tag (meaning people who search for [tag:xna] would find all questions regardless of version).

Comment: @Alex did you know you can search with wildcards, like `xna*`? So no need to do what you are proposing.

Comment: I bet you can do all kind of searches, but that does not remove the fact, that we now have 2 tags, that users should tag when creating question for xna. 4 years since last update and announcement that no more is coming, so I don't see the difference between xna and xna-4.0.

Comment: @congusbongus Ah, I was not aware of that functionality. Thanks for letting me know. It does seem a bit redundant now with that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

I find your comment on leaving 3.1 alone while removing 4.0 contradictory. Thinking in other contexts, considering XNA likely isn't getting a new release, so let's say Unity for example. Do we pretend that anything tagged just Unity is the latest and greatest version? What happens when a new release comes out? Do we go back and retag or do we leave it alone and create a new tag for those who are still on the old version who might post future questions? Just seems an odd way to handle it.

If there are only 6 questions tagged XNA 3.1 then I think we should just merge everything into XNA since the versioning hasn't seemed to help all that much.

**To clarify...**

The issue may actually just be with my understanding of synonyms and how they work on the site. For me it's import to be able to understand and distinguish that while XNA 4.0 may be the same as XNA, XNA is not always going to be the same as XNA 4.0

Comment: Microsoft has announced that XNA is not getting updates anymore, they are building new, something like XNA, but it's not the same. So in that light, xna and 4.0 are the same, but leaves 3.1 there, incase someone is still using it. But yeah, merging all is option too.

Comment: Right. I just don't want to set a weird precedent that makes no sense for other technologies because other technologies aren't dead.

Comment: Maybe edit the 6 3.1 questions to state they are version 3.1, and merge the tags.

Comment: So as I understand it your position in this answer is "merge everything so we only have one XNA tag?" (If that isn't the case I'd like to post an answer that says exactly that, so we can see where the consensus is).

Comment: Yes - I would merge the XNA versioned tags into the XNA tag is what I was trying to say here.

Answer (score 1):

The [guidelines for versioned tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/what-are-the-guidelines-for-using-version-specific-tags/85744#85744) are basically:

- don't use them
- if you use them, the context should be one where the subject matter of the question is specifically tied to the versioning in some fashion
- the "latest" version should probably not have a version tag in most cases

In the case of XNA, we know the latest version is 4 and that there will be no further releases. However, we also know that 4 has some significant breaking changes, so there is merit to knowing version 4 is used in place of an earlier version (thus I think the last guideline is too weak relatively to apply here).

My vote, thus, would be to do nothing here. `xna-4.0` should be for questions using XNA 4 or specifically concerning XNA 4's breaking changes. `xna-3.1` should be used for earlier-version specific questions. `xna` should be used for questions where it doesn't matter (basically, everything else).

We should *not* do anything that removes `xna` as a tag in any form (because version tags are "evil"); as a moderator I'd probably veto any such action, because the `xna` tag itself is far more natural. I would not, however, be opposed to simply wiping out the versioning altogether and folding everything in to `xna`.

Comment: Good link find. I think these are good guidelines and my concern with doing nothing is that we might have a big mess on our hands that would need cleaning up, as in we would have a lot of improperly tagged xna-4.0 tags (which maybe isn't a problem?) and the tag should be reserved for questions such as this one http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75896/renderstate-in-xna-4

Comment: If the "mess" really isn't a concern and we just take an effort to properly tag questions moving forward based on these guidelines I am perfectly ok with taking no action on these tags.